# error argument "df1" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

the code below:

```
# 10*. Pipe that to a ggplot command and create a histogram with 4 bins. 
# Hint: you will NOT write ggplot(df, aes(...)) because the df is already piped in. 
# Instead, just write: ggplot(aes(...)) etc.
# Title the histogram, "Distribution of Sunday tips for bills over $20"
# Feel free to style the plot (not required; this would be a typical exploratory
# analysis where only you will see it, so it doesn't have to be perfect).
df %>%
  filter(total_bill > 20 & day == "Sun") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=total_bill, fill=size)) +
    geom_histogram(bins=4) +
    ggtitle("Distribution of Sunday tips for bills over $20")
```

produces the error:

```
Error in df(.) : argument "df1" is missing, with no default
```

What is the reason, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a minimal sample of the data, so that we can execute the code? Then it is easier to help. Also, did you load ggplot2 und dplyr before this code snippet?

Answer (score 6):

Type `?df` in your console, and you will see that `df` is a function with the following argument.

```
df(x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE)
```

where `df1` is an argument. So the error message is saying that R cannot find the first argument for the `df` function.

It seems like in this code example, your friend is trying to put a data frame called `df` into the `filter` function from the `dplyr` package and the `ggplot` function from the `ggplot2` package to create a plot.

So my guess is your friend needs to define `df` as a data frame. Otherwise, R will think `df` is a function and keep throwing error.

By the way, since `df` is a defined function in R, it is not a good name for a data frame. However, people use `df` as a name for a data frame all the time. Try a different name, such as `dat`, for the name of a data frame next time.

Comment: Heck, I have been using R for over a decade now, and I didn't know that `df` is actually a function!